# Join two csv files into one  in java

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have two csv files with multiple columns from multiple tables.I am using opencsv to make csv files.
I want to make one csv file containing all the columns from both files.
There is one common column in both the files.
But number of records are  not same.
Please suggest something. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: Joining two files simply mean i want to add all the columns in one file..It is not the database join .
I want the combined csv file and use it to in some tool to generate a pdf

Comment: If they don't have the same columns and different line counts, **how** are you going to merge them? What's the logic here? What would be the output file?

Comment: *"Please suggest something."*  It does not sound like this is data suitable for a CSV.  Find another storage structure.

Comment: I simply want all the columns in one csv file and further use this csv file..This is the challenge that i am facing as the tables are not related

Comment: on what basis do you want to join the records then ? seems like you will be just appending one file to the other and inserting default values for the missing columns

Comment: sorry i have one column common.. i re-checked.. updated my question..sorry for confusion

Comment: are you trying to do something like a database JOIN where you link the lines in the two files where the common column is used as a key?

Comment: What is this common column? Was it a primary/foreign key in the original tables? Can you add description of the fields you have? Can you explain why do you need to "merge" the files?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? What exactly doesn't work? I can only see your requirements specification. Is it yet another rent-a-coder "question"?

Comment: -1: C'mon, this problem is far larger than the usual "Please help me write a regexp for ..." that some people are willing to Just Do for questioners... If you're going to ask for help from strangers, at least put in some effort yourself.

Comment: You can check [csv-merger](https://github.com/riyadparvez/csv-merger) github project.

Answer (score 4):

Load one file into a dictionary keyed by the common column value, then append all the records of the 2nd file to the respective entry in the dictionary (again by common column value).
Finally, write all dictionary k,v pairs to a new file.

improvised example:

```
CSVReader r1 = ...; // reader of 1st file
CSVReader r2 = ...; // reader of 2nd file

HashMap<String,String[]> dic = new HashMap<String,String[]>();

int commonCol = 1; // index of the commonColumn

r1.readNext(); // skip header
String[] line = null;
while ((line = r1.readNext()) != null)
{
  dic.add(line[commonCol],line)
}

commonCol = 2; // index of the commonColumn in the 2nd file

r2.readNext(); // skip header
String[] line = null;
while ((line = r2.readNext()) != null)
{
  if (dic.keySet().contains(line[commonCol])
  {
    // append line to existing entry
  }
  else
  {
     // create a new entry and pre-pend it with default values
     // for the columns of file1
  }
}

foreach (String[] line : dic.valueSet())
{
   // write line to the output file.
}
```

Comment: i've added a basic incomplete (!) example of how it should look, try to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this if we know which columns have the duplicate data

```
    int n1,n2;//stores the serial number of the column that has the duplicate data
    BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f1)));
    BufferedReader br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f2)));
    String line1,line2;
    while((line1=br1.readLine())!=null && (line2=br2.readLine())!=null){
        String line=line1+","+line2;
        String newL="";
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        for(int i=1;i<=st.countTokens();i++){
            if((i==n1)||(i==n1+n2))
                continue;
            else
                newL=newL+","+st.nextToken();
        }
        String l=newL.substring(1);
        //write this line to the output file
    }
```